# Use FaceTime with the same Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, facetime

I and my wife own three Apple devices. MacBook Pro, iPad 2 (only Wi-Fi) and iPhone 4S. All of these are registered with the same Apple ID and Gmail account. With FaceTime I can call to IPhone, but I cannot call from my iPhone. Probably because iPad or MacBook do not have a unique id. How can this be fixed so I can use FaceTime in any direction? I do not want more than one Apple ID as it makes trouble in App Store and iCloud.

Answer (score 4):

You can add another email address for FaceTime in your iPad:

[image: Facetime Options iPad]

This will allow you to call your iPad uniquely with this id.

Similarly, you can add another email address to your MacBook Pro's Facetime:

[image: Facetime options MacBook]

Answer (score 1):

You have only on apple id, but do you have several emails ?
In this case, you can add on your Macbook or your iPad another email address on which you will be call on Facetime.

For example :
Your apple id account : myname@gmail.com
To call to your iPhone, use your phone number.
To call to your iPad, use your apple id email.
To call to your Macbook add a new adress in FaceTime preferences :

[image: Factime Preferences]

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

FaceTime, the App Store, and iCloud can all use separate Apple ID's for this reason.

Your iPhone will also register its phone number with Apple's servers, so it can be reached there as well.

In your case, I would recommend making a new ID either for each device, or each person, and only use this ID for FaceTime for now. A limitation to this is that while you can add multiple ID's for FaceTime to recognize, these emails can not be used for another Apple ID. If you make one for each device, you will not have to worry about this limitation.

For example, my Apple ID is tied to iCloud and FaceTime and all my devices. I have a separate account for iTunes. I can not set up FaceTime to use the iCloud account and the iTunes account.